# Jenkins: Restricting the ability to build to logged-in users

Tags: jenkins, automated-builds

I'm configuring Jenkins.

I want to make it so that only users who are logged in can run a job, so we have a record of who does what. The problem is, we have a lot of users, and a lot of jobs, and I don't want to set individual users on all the jobs. I also don't want to allow anonymous to kick off builds, and I don't want everyone to be able to configure jobs.

So, is there an easy way to require that a user is logged in if they want to "build now?" without adding each individual user to the permissions list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jenkins has "*authenticated*" and "*anonymous*" groups which can be used in global configuration. Give "anonymous" only read access, give "authenticated" permission to start builds.

Comment: It was existence of the "authenticated" user group that I didn't know about! Thank you!

Comment: I have installed [Role based authorization strategy plugin] https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin., added authenticated group and role under manage roles and that works awesome.